# Wait for QueueUserWorkItem to Complete

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool, parallel-processing

If I add jobs to the thread pool with `QueueUserWorkItem`... how do I keep my program from going forward until all jobs are completed?

I know I could add some logic to keep the app from running until all jobs are completed, but I want to know if there is something like `Thread.Join()` or if there's any way to retrieve each thread that is being assigned a job.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use events to sync. Like this:

```
private static ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public static void Main()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(arg => DoWork());
    resetEvent.WaitOne();
}

public static void DoWork()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    resetEvent.Set();
}
```

If you don't want to embed event set into your method, you could do something like this:

```
var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    arg => 
    {
        DoWork();
        resetEvent.Set();
    });
resetEvent.WaitOne();
```

For multiple items:

```
var events = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

foreach(var job in jobs)
{   
    var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        arg =>
        {
            DoWork(job);
            resetEvent.Set();
        });
    events.Add(resetEvent);
}
WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray());
```

Comment: This would easily work for queuing one job at a time... but If I had multiple jobs then I would need a buckle to control it? Wouldn't I? If not... How is that adaptable to multiple queued jobs?

Comment: this has a limit of 64 items. As the other answers show there are more suitable constructs for dealing with multiple tasks, but if you are targeting older profiles you can use a single event and use a counter decremented with Interlocked.Decrement

Comment: The UI thread freezes when I use the resetEvent.WaitOne() method. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 20):

The best way to do this is to use the `CountdownEvent` class. This is a fairly well established pattern and is about as scalable as it gets.

```
using (var finished = new CountdownEvent(1))
{
  foreach (var workitem in workitems)
  {
    var capture = workitem; // Used to capture the loop variable in the lambda expression.
    finished.AddCount(); // Indicate that there is another work item.
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
      (state) =>
      {
        try
        {
          ProcessWorkItem(capture);
        }
        finally
        {
          finished.Signal(); // Signal that the work item is complete.
        }
      }, null);
  }
  finished.Signal(); // Signal that queueing is complete.
  finished.Wait(); // Wait for all work items to complete.
}
```

Comment: It is great solution, unfortunately it only works in .NET 4 and up.

Comment: @BrianGideon Excellent answer! But how would I be able to cancel the threads prematurely with `CountdownEvent`? Like if I was using this in a Windows Forms application and the user closes the form but there are threads running.

Comment: @JohnOdom: This answer is a bit outdated. A more contemporary solution is to use the Task Parallel Library for stuff like this. Anyway, included in the TPL is the cooperative cancellation classes. That's what should be used to gracefully terminate threads.

Comment: @BrianGideon what would you recommend from TPL for this case?

Answer (score 5):

You can use .NET's [Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997287.aspx) class to achieve this.

```
Barrier barrier = new Barrier(3); 
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (state) =>
    {
       foo();
       barrier.SignalAndWait();
    }, null);
}
barrier.SignalAndWait();
```

Comment: DrewR, could you provide an example that answers the question?

Comment: I added an example - note this is a .NET 4 feature