# How to query the Smart Thread Pool to get the Current Status of a Job?

Tags: c#, threadpool

Currently I am using Smart Thread Pool from AMIB in my .Net app. I have created Jobs and Queued them in the pool for execution as shown below:

```
WorkItemCallback wiCallback = new WorkItemCallback(job.QueuedExecution);
IWorkItemResult wiResult = mySmartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(wiCallback,         (WorkItemPriority)job.Priority);
```

In any point of time how can I query the ThreadPool to get the Current Status i.e. Queued/Running/Cancelled by passing the JobId i.e.

```
TaskStatus mySmartThreadPool.GetCurrentStatus(string jobId);
```

OR how to get a Reference to the already Queued item from Smart Thread Pool?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task will be run by a thread in the pool. The pool is in control of the thread.

But in the link below, there is an example that you can use to check if a thread has finished or not

[Wait for QueueUserWorkItem to Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529659/wait-for-queueuserworkitem-to-complete)